# about PHP array_diff( ) functions usage?

Tags: php, array-difference

When i use array_diff() functions like; `$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);`

It turns like;  Array( [5] => XXXXXX )

But i dont want to show " Array ( "index here"  ) ", only XXXXX part. How can i show only XXXXX?
Thanks for every comments...

Comment: My comment: http://php.net/array + http://php.net/array_values + http://php.net/arrays

Comment: What if the difference will be more than one element? What will be XXXXX in that case? `array_diff` [returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

Answer (score 4):

Obtain the first element that is different *-or-* `NULL` if there is no difference.

```
list($result) = array_values(array_diff($array1, $array2)) + [NULL];
```

You can do:

```
var_dump($result);
```

See [Demo](http://eval.in/4565).

To just out put the value you can do:

```
foreach($result as $value){
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: it shows only one difference. For example: http://eval.in/4599

Comment: Try this http://eval.in/4804